# Can't figure out why background picture doesn't fill all screen

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I can't figure out why background picture doesn't fill all screen. There some fields around where superview could be seen.
Maybe there is something with that it is presented modally via segue?

This is what I get
[image]
And this is what I want to achieve. Note that superview background fills all screen width:

[image]

Comment: Because you have pinned the background to the superview's _margins_ rather than its edges?

Answer (score -1):

There is the problem in pixels of your image , preview your image and go to adjust size then give perfect height and weight as per your background view and use it